# Appmaker panel & canvas height

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a long form in a panel with lots of controls, however the Canvas/panel editor has a limited height of about 1000px and refuses to scroll to allow adding more controls.
I am able to make the panel 2000px and enable overflow to get the panel itself to scroll once the app is deployed, but how do I manage to drag/drop new controls/widgets?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the canvas is a round control which allows it to be extended beyond the default and therefore allows long controls.

Comment: This should be an amended to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A page's **main panel** should have a dimension property in the property editor, that specifies height and width. I'm able to set it to much larger values (e.g. 5000 pixels).

Once the main panel is large enough, you should be able to scroll down in it and drop new widgets where you need them to be.

It's also easy to accidentially drop in new panels and then stuff new widgets into the wrong panel, so make sure the panel structure is really what you believe it is (e.g. via the structure editor).